# How to get distinct logins for particular month in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data like below:

```
userid action login_month
2      login  1
2      login  1
2      login  1
5      login  3
5      login  3
9      login  7
9      login  7
```

I need output as unique logins per month like:

```
userid action login_month
2      login  1
5      login  3
9      login  7
```

Can anyone please suggest for a solution in mysql?

Comment: Please specific with correct table values. It is confusing what are showing in the values

Comment: I have select the data from log table that i have given above, from that i need unique logins. Please let me know if more details needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select distinct * from logins;
```

this will make your work done .

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6c9a0/2)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The above is the select query from the log table, from that i need unique logins. The below query i have used to select the above data.

Comment: select distinct userid,FROM_UNIXTIME(time,'%d-%m-%y') as logindate,action,month(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) month from mdl_log where action = 'login' 
order by userid,month

Comment: No, its not a solution. I'm searching for perfect result. (ie.Unique logins for each month). Thanks.